# Convert a non english character to ASCII and reconvert to english using javascript

Tags: javascript, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I have a non English character 'স' . I can convert it to ASCII code writing this:

```
var x='স';    
document.write(x.charCodeAt(0)); //output is 224
```

I need to reconvert it to English. 
I tried:

```
document.write(String.fromCharCode(224)); //output is à
```

Obviously স != à

Why this is occurring? How can I re-convert to English?

Comment: Hm, I cannot reproduce. I'm getting `2488` for that character, not `224`.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. ASCII is not English but it is used to represent English characters.

Comment: I checked and got 2488, reconvert still received: স

Comment: WTH do you mean by "*re-convert to English*"? Do you mean that you want convert the character code *back to a string*?

Comment: I tried coping the exact character from your question and got a character code of `2488`. `String.fromCharCode(2488)` also returns `"স"`. It looks to be a problem elsewhere.

Comment: @Bergi , yes I want convert the character code back to a string?

Comment: @lezed1, but why I get 224?

Comment: Your code should work. Maybe your character encoding is broken, and you don't actually put `x='স'` but rather something like `x='à…'`?

Comment: I'm using Chrome (on Linux) with English as my system language. Are you using a browser that supports Unicode? Is English you system language?

Comment: @lezed1, I am on firefox (Ubuntu 14.04). My language is not English, but bengali. Is this a  (firefox)browser issue?

Comment: @Bergi, yes, I think my character encoding is broken. What can I do?

Comment: I just tested in Firefox 39.0.3 and the `charCode` was `2488`. I got the same results. This could be form your language settings or improper Unicode support (I'm assuming this character isn't in ASCII, but rather in Unicode).

Comment: @lezed1, how can I set my encoding system to ASCII instead of UNICODE?

Comment: @partho: Hm, fix it? I recommend to use UTF-8, it is most common. No, you may not use ASCII, as স is not within the ASCII range.

Comment: @Bergi you solved ! Why didn't answer instead of comment?

Comment: @partho: Because it was a pure guess, your question doesn't show the cause. I think the question should be closed as "too localised" rather than answered.